# Memory Error while applying a .loc filter on Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, large-data

I have a large dataframe with about 392 million rows and 9 columns. I want to apply a filter on the data set to extract a subset.

Here my original dataset is `dh_activity_recos`

```
dh_activity_approved = dh_activity_recos.loc[dh_activity_recos.approved_flag == 1]
```

Now, when I apply this filter I get the following memory error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt01/eh-datasci/ravinder/working/final_recos_processing.py", line 144, in <module>
    dh_activity_approved = dh_activity_recos.loc[dh_activity_recos.approved_flag == 1]
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1227, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1344, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1239, in _getbool_axis
    raise self._exception(detail)
KeyError: MemoryError()
```

I am not able to understand the exact reason behind this. I have checked with `dir()` command; there are not any other memory-consuming resources except this large dataset. Moreover, I am executing this on cloud with 128GB RAM, so I'm not sure why this error is surfacing.

Comment: I've been having this same issue. So, my best guess is that while pandas' Data Frames are being indexed on, the data frame makes copies of itself that eat up memory. May be due to some lazy evaluation going on.

Comment: There might be some other series floating around that you might need to dereference. On this line you generate 2 new Series (`dh_activity_recos.approved_flag == 1` and `dh_activity_approved`). If your dataset is so large, this might just tip over the memory., `dask` might be a better option than pandas

Comment: @MaartenFabré Dask did the trick! Though I'm still using Pandas to create the initial DataFrames since Dask doesn't recommend calling the DataFrame constructor directly...